# raid 1 + OS drive windows 7 ep45 ud3p

Tags: raid, software-raid, raid-1

I have an existing drive with my OS and data on it, because of shortage of storage, I bought two Samsung 2TB drives to form a RAID 1 configuration. I understand that RAID 1 is a redundancy config. - I was wondering if the motherboard Gigabyte EP45 UD3P lets me keep using the current single drive for my OS and add those two drives in RAID 1 for storage?

Could you recommend some tutorial on how this is done?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be no problem.

- Plug in both drives
- In the motherboard RAID setup, create a Mirrored volume (RAID 1)
- Boot up your OS, and load up the disk manager
- Select/enable your 2TB Raid 1 volume and format it, assign it a drive letter.

Comment: Oh wow, that's it? Thanks first for your swifty response  - I'm trying it now.

Comment: Hi NoCarrier, I did the motherboard RAID setup, and the screen has been on the Verifying DMI Pool Data for a few minutes now, is that normal?

Comment: Hopefully you did it right and did not accidentally wipe out your OS drive.

Comment: Yeah, I got it right I think, I followed the manual's instruction. -- I finally just now got past the verifying dmi thing and there's just this start up error now my windows installation is giving me. it asks  for the start up disc and I am feeding it now for repair... will report more

Comment: And if I don't choose launch windows statup repair, and choose start up normally instead, it reboots itself

Comment: Guys, I decided to use that dynamic disk business. And it went well now. - I went back to the BIOS setting and disabled the RAID setting for the SATA, and Windows booted right up. Then I read something that Windows can do Software raid, so I thought I should just use that. And it seems to work now!